# Meromorphic function analytic at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Let $f\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a meromorphic function analytic at $0$ such that $f\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)=\frac{n}{2n+1}$ for all $n\geq1$. Show:

$a)\hspace{0.25cm} f(2)=\frac{1}{4}$

$b)\hspace{0.25cm} f$ has a simple pole at $z=-2$.

I'm unsure how to proceed. I tried writing the power series expansion around $0$ but really get anywhere. I also tried writing $f$ as a rational function but that didn't help either. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{n}}
$$
and as $f$ is analytic at $z=0$, then the [Identity Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) applies and hence
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{2+z}.
$$

Comment: ($f(z)-\frac{1}{2+z}$ is analytic around $z=0$ and has infinitely many zeros accumulating there, so it must be identically zero)

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis, where do you use that $f$ is meromorphic?

Comment: Meromorphic in $\mathbb C$ means that it is analytic everywhere except of countably many points, where $f$ has poles. It is analytic in a neighborhood of 0, and that's all we need.